# Excel VBA: code to copy cells from sheet to new one

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below codes to create sheets and rename it from specific list in the master sheet 
I need a help to add a code to copy some cells from another sheet ( pay slip ) to be pest in each of these new sheets

```
Sub CreateSheetsFromAList()
    Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range
    Set MyRange = Sheets("MASTER").Range("E9:E27")
    Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

    For Each MyCell In MyRange
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value ' renames the new worksheet

    Next MyCell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Which Cells from "Pay Slip" should be copied? 
For example, I will assume that you want to copy cell (1,1) & cells(2,1) from "Pay Slip" to be copied to new cell.

Modify your code as explained below.

```
For Each MyCell In MyRange
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value ' renames the new worksheet

    ''''Include the Copy steps from PaySlip sheet below this
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).cells(1,1) = Sheets("Pay Slip").cells(1,1)
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).cells(2,1) = Sheets("Pay Slip").cells(2,1)

Next MyCell
```

Comment: Hi .. this copy the pay slip sheet but i had to change to ..( Sheets(Sheets.Count).range("A3:L33") = Sheets("Pay Slip").Range("A3:L33").value) .. but i will need the formula and formatting too 
which is not there

Comment: In that case, use the below code to copy the data, formula and formatting.
'    Sheets("Pay Slip").Range("A3:L33").Copy
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A4").Select'

Answer (score 0):

You could use .Copy & .PasteSpecial method of Range-object.. Here a simple example -

```
Sub copySomeRange(r As Range, target As Range)
r.Copy
target.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
End Sub

Sub callMeExample()
Call copySomeRange(Range("A1:A5"), Range("B1"))
End Sub
```

The first Sub() does the copying so U can use that part of the code as is. Just add your logic to what to copy.